# How to move an element from one place to another in the DOM using plain JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I know how to do it in jQUery (untested but should work):

```
$('#foo').html().appendTo('#bar');
$('#foo').remove();
```

But how to do this in plain JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
field = document.getElementById('e');
document.getElementById('x').innerHTML = field.parentNode.innerHTML;
field.parentNode.removeChild(field);
```

this is ONE solution, you can search for [clonenode](http://www.w3schools.com/dom/met_element_clonenode.asp) too.

Answer (score 1):

Your jQuery code can be done like this in plain javascript:

```
var foo = document.getElementById("foo"),
    bar = document.getElementById("bar");
bar.innerHTML = foo.innerHTML;
foo.parentNode.removeChild(foo);
```

But this just copies the html code inside `foo` to `bar` as a string, then removes `foo` from the DOM.

Moving the nodes is also possible, like this:

```
var foo = document.getElementById("foo"),
    bar = document.getElementById("bar");
bar.innerHTML = "";
for (var node in foo.childNodes) {
    bar.appendChild(node);
}
foo.parentNode.removeChild(foo);
```

This will move the actual child nodes of `foo` to `bar`, and then remove the now empty `foo`.

Answer (score 1):

At its simplest, there's this possibility:

```
var foo = document.getElementById('foo');
document.getElementById('bar').innerHTML = foo.innerHTML;
foo.parentNode.removeChild(foo);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/CESGq/).

And, using a function to minimise repetition:

```
function moveTo(source,target){
    if (!source || !target) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        var children = source.childNodes;
        while (children.length){
            target.appendChild(children[0]);
        }
        source.parentNode.removeChild(source);
    }
}

var bar = document.getElementById('bar'),
    foo = document.getElementById('foo');

moveTo(foo, bar);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/CESGq/1/).

Answer (score 0):

Creating an element

```
   <div id="div1">
     <p id="p1">This is a paragraph.</p>
     <p id="p2">This is another paragraph.</p>
    </div>

    <script>
    var para=document.createElement("p");
     var node=document.createTextNode("This is new.");
    para.appendChild(node);

     var element=document.getElementById("div1");
    element.appendChild(para);
    </script>
```

Removing an element ( you must know the parent)

```
    <div id="div1">
     <p id="p1">This is a paragraph.</p>
     <p id="p2">This is another paragraph.</p>
    </div>
    <script>
     var parent=document.getElementById("div1");
      var child=document.getElementById("p1");
      parent.removeChild(child);
    </script>
```

Brought to you by http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_elements.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can append an existing node to another one, and thus moving it to the new location:

```
var move_me = document.getElementById("to_move"),
    new_parent = document.getElementById("new_parent");
// the magic. appendChild moves elements
new_parent.appendChild(move_me);
```

See also on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild). Doesn't get any simpler. Note that this will keep event listener and stuff, what normally is a desired outcome, but keep in mind if you dont need them anymore. And probably it is much more efficient than all `.innerHTML` solutions.